# Read out cisco Ie3300 modbus tcp ip

Tags: python, modbus, cisco

Cisco switch is enabled for modbusTCP ip...

```
cisco#show scada modbus tcp server
Summary: enabled, running, process id 330

Conn Stats: listening on port 502, 5 max simultaneous connections
    0 current client connections
    6 total accepted connections, 0 accept connection errors
    6 closed connections, 0 close connection errors

Send Stats: 7 tcp msgs sent, 63 tcp bytes sent, 0 tcp errors
    0 responses sent, 7 exceptions sent, 0 send errors

Recv Stats: 7 tcp msgs received, 84 tcp bytes received, 0 tcp errors
    7 requests received, 0 receive errors
```

...but if i read out a register --> https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/cisco_ie3X00/software/17_3/b_cip-modbus_17-3_iot_switch_cg/m_modbus.html
...get back NONE for demonstration purpose i did use all 3 methods...to check if they make a different..

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
try:
    #create new object
    c = ModbusClient(host=SERVER_HOST, port=SERVER_PORT, debug=False, auto_open=True)
except ValueError:
    #something went wrong...wrong ip, server port ?
    print("Error with host or port params")  
    
#start the while loop
while loop: 
    try:
        #connection is open
        if c.is_open():
            #loop through the coils
            print(f"Connected to {SERVER_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}")
            print(c.read_coils(1000,64))
            print(c.read_holding_registers(1000,64))
            print(c.read_input_registers(1000,64))
            loop = False
        else:
            #connection is not open
            print(f"Trying to connect to {SERVER_HOST}: SERVER_PORT}")           
            #try to open it again
            c.open()
            #give it some time
            sleep(1)
    #break loop if keyboard interrupt...        
    except KeyboardInterrupt: 
        #break
```

when executing

```
Trying to connect to 192.168.178.95:502
Connect to 192.168.178.95:502
None
None
None
```

setting "debug=True"

```
Trying to connect to 192.168.178.95:502
Connected to 192.168.178.95:502
Tx
[B5 1D 00 00 00 06 01] 01 03 E8 00 40 
Rx
[B5 1D 00 00 00 03 01] 81 01 
except (code 1)
None
Tx
[B7 1A 00 00 00 06 01] 03 03 E8 00 40 
Rx
[B7 1A 00 00 00 03 01] 83 02 
except (code 2)
None
Tx
[8B 3A 00 00 00 06 01] 04 03 E8 00 40 
Rx
[8B 3A 00 00 00 03 01] 84 01 
except (code 1)
None
```

Does not work ...what am i doing wrong...using both functions...

Comment: One issue might be that the `1000` in the manual is hex (if you look down a bit you will see `10C0`); try requesting `0x1000`.

Comment: OH...should have thought about that ..thanks....works... i guess should go to work instead working until 1:50 in the morning

Answer (score 0):

Should have used hex format ....0x1000

```
   print(f"Connected to {SERVER_HOST}:{SERVER_PORT}") 
   #print(c.read_coils(0x1000,64))
   print(c.read_holding_registers(0x1000,64))
   #print(c.read_input_registers(0x1000,64))
```

now i get the following back ...

```
   Trying to connect to 192.168.178.95:502
   Connected to 192.168.178.95:502
   [18281, 26465, 25193, 29765, 29800, 25970, 28261, 29745, 12081, 0, 0,    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```